# Bring entities on draft mode Strapi

Tags: strapi

**Scenario**

I'm trying to get all entities from an endpoint, the ones on draft mode, and the ones on published mode.
I know that if I want to post on draft mode, I have to post *published_at on null* on the body request.

If I do:

```
/posts?published_at_null=true
```

that returns an empty array.

**Question**

How can I do to return **ALL** the posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is on the documentation

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#publication-state

But quick answer, URL + '?_publicationState=preview'

https://forum.strapi.io/t/draft-and-posted-entities/3576/2

Comment: The correct URL to the docs is now https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#publication-state

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a custom control that will fetch all the entries.you cannot fetch draft data using the existing restapi urls.

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async findUnpublished(ctx) {

    //getting all the existing articles, no meter if they have unpublished status
    let result = await strapi.query('posts').find();
    
    //sanitize them to hide all private fields
    let articles = sanitizeEntity(result, {
        model: strapi.models['posts'],
    });
    
    //return result to the /findUnpublished API
    ctx.send(articles);
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually, you can, it is on the documentation. Thanks for the possible solution